# How to fix error: Web3.providers.HttpProvider is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, web3js

I have problem in Web3 provider recently.
I have used HttpProvider as Web3 Provider, but now I cannot use it.
Previous projects are also not executed.
Here is my code and Error:

Code:

```
const url = `https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/{my_api_key}`;
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(url));
```

Error Message:

> const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(url));
> ^
>
> TypeError: Web3.providers.HttpProvider is not a constructor.
> ...

How can I fix it?

So I have tried to fix this error by controlling Web3 Version, changing providers, etc, but not fixed.

Comment: If the url you have provided is the url you are using, you are missing a $ for the interpolation to work. It should be `https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/${my_api_key}`;

Answer (score 5):

For me, wrapping works

replace
const Web3 = require('web3)

with
const {Web3} = require('web3')

Answer (score 1):

Try to install web3 version 1.10.0

npm uninstall web3

then

npm i web3@1.10.0

Comment: not working. 
It is showing in package.json file but when --version . it says not found

error while web3 --version
"The term 'web3' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the       
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try    
again."

Comment: after some time, it got worked